# Is my truth table for the formula: $A ∧ (A ∨ C) \implies (C ∨ B)$ correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is my truth table for the formula: $A \land (A \lor C) \implies (C \lor B)$ correct?

[image]

Comment: In a word: yes, it is.

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   Why did you doubt it?

$A\wedge (A\vee C)$ is true only when $A$ is true.

$C\vee B$ is true when either of $B$ or $C$ are true.

$A\wedge (A\vee C)\to(C\vee B)$ is true when at least one from: $A$ is false, $B$ is true, or $C$ is true.

---

Okay, perhaps, to be strict, you should include a column for $A\vee C$, to show, rather than merely *asserting*, that $A\wedge (A\vee C)$ is equivalent to $A$.